# Change data on mysql when user closed the page

Tags: jquery, mysql

I need to update a MySQL database when a user wants to close the page or the browser.

I know how do this with a *button click*, but I don't know how I can update **MySql** when the user closes the tab.

This is my code using *button click*

```
$( "#buttonx2" ).click(function() {
var p=$("#przeslana").val();
var dataString = 'text='+p;
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "rozmowa_del.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     });

window.location.href = "rozmawiaj.php";
}
```

How I can do this when a user wants to close the page?

Answer (score 2):

Try Jquery's [Unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)

```
$(window).unload(function() {
        var p=$("#przeslana").val();
        var dataString = 'text='+p;
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rozmowa_del.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        });

   });
```

The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates away from the page. This could mean one of many things. The user could have clicked on a link to leave the page, or typed in a new URL in the address bar. The forward and back buttons will trigger the event. Closing the browser window will cause the event to be triggered.